# How to get USB 3 camera to show on Ubuntu VirtualBox?

Tags: 16.04, usb, virtualbox, camera

USB 3 camera does not show on Ubuntu VirtualBox.

**Details:**

I connected an `Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 410` camera to a `USB 3.0` port.

In `Windows 7,` the camera shows as a *connected USB device.*

However, even when I filter for it in `Ubuntu 16.04` on `VirtualBox 5.1.12 r112440 (Qt5.6.2),` on the same `Windows 7` machine, viz.:

[image: Filter USB device]

it does not show in Linux `lsusb:`

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

### Any ideas how can I get the USB 3 camera to show on Ubuntu VirtualBox?

Comment: Unplug the device, run `sudo udev monitor` in a command line, then plug the device in again.  Do you see a lot of output indicating the kernel and the system are recognizing the device?  (My guess is if it's not showing in `lsusb` it's not, but let's make sure)

Comment: Unless your camera is a HD device that requires USB3, try connecting it to a USB2 port, change your VB config from USB3 to USB2 controller, and see if the cam shows up then.

Comment: Thank @heynnema. Alas, the camera is a 3D camera that works only on USB3.